# How do I insert a transition between two clips in Vegas?

Tags: vegas-pro, transitions

I have opened an old-ish video project of mine that I've been creating in Sony Vegas Pro 14. I have some transitions between clips that I notice overlap evenly between the clips' associated audio tracks:

[image]

And for a better indication of what I mean (i.e. this is what it looks like when you drag the clip that is transitioned into away from its preceding clip):

[image]

The problem is I have forgotten how I applied the transition like this and every time I try to apply a transition to a new clip, it just overlaps the preceding one.

Could someone please explain how to apply a transition as has been done here? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly. You're talking about transitions on the audio track, but in the screenshot there are only transitions on the video. Are you asking how to add the video transition? Generally you just make the two clips overlap and then drag a transition from the transitions window onto the overlap.

Comment: @nwsp Yes, that is what I mean.